# how to add line chart in October CMS?

Tags: html, laravel, octobercms

I want to add a line chart as a control chart in one of the widget pages in October CMS. CMS has pre-built classes for bar chart and pie chart. I was wondering if they  have similar classes for other kind of analytics data.
I want to add the line chart prebuilt class to an html partials page, that can be used as a widget in october cms.

Comment: It would be good if you gave some more references and links to make clear what you are talking about. (I assume that may be the reason that people voted you down here, although I find this a bit harsh.) In this case it seems that you are talking about things like this: https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/chart and you are looking for another type of chart besides those mentioned there. I'm afraid, if it's not listed there in the docs, then such a UI element does not exist prebuilt in October.

Comment: lol thanks. agreed, I don't think cms has it. However you can use a third party reference such as chart.js and place it in <script> tags to include a line chart.

Comment: My issue right now is that the widget(partials view) doesn't like this script from chart.js and it doesn't load anything on the page. Need to debug this. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: It seems I was wrong. The functionality seems to be there. See my answer below.

Comment: So it seems this was a really good question if it ends up revealing a feature that was not public in the docs, and the downvoters should really start to think on how to be a bit more constructive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are talking about things like this: https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/chart and you are looking for another type of chart besides those mentioned there.

I wanted to say if such a thing is not listed there then probably it does not exist. But... hey... I just went looking into the backend UI JS code.

Look at this file in your October app root: `{% app root %}/modules/system/assets/ui/js/chart.line.js`

```
/*
 * Line Chart Plugin
 *
 * Data attributes:
 * - data-control="chart-line" - enables the line chart plugin
 * - data-reset-zoom-link="#reset-zoom" - specifies a link to reset zoom
 * - data-zoomable - indicates that the chart is zoomable
 * - data-time-mode="weeks" - if the "weeks" value is specified and the xaxis mo
de is "time", the X axis labels will be displayed as week end dates.
 * - data-chart-options="xaxis: {mode: 'time'}" - specifies the Flot configurati
on in JSON format. See https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md for detai
ls.
 *
 * Data sets are defined with the SPAN elements inside the chart element: <span 
data-chart="dataset" data-set-data="[0,0],[1,19]">
 * Data set elements could contain data attributes with names in the format "dat
a-set-color". The names for the data set
 * attributes are described in the Flot documentation: https://github.com/flot/f
lot/blob/master/API.md#data-format
 *
 * JavaScript API:
 * $('.chart').chartLine({ resetZoomLink:'#reset-zoom' })
 *
```

So the functionality is there, it seems, but it's not in the public docs. Looks like you could try out something like this

```
<div
    class="control-chart"
    data-control="chart-line"
    style="min-height:400px"
    data-zoomable="1"
    data-reset-zoom-link="#reset-zoom"
    data->
    <span data-chart="dataset" data-set-label="Graph me tender" data-set-data="[0,0],[1,5],[3,8],[4,2],[5,6]">
         Graph me tender
    </span>
    <span data-chart="dataset" data-set-label="Graph me sweet" data-set-data="[0,0],[1,5],[3,8],[4,2]">
        Graph me sweet
    </span>
</div>
<a id="#reset-zoom" href="#">Reset zoom</a>
```

[image: the resulting graph]
**(Edit: There was a somewhat "dirty" tweak necessary here: I added a min-height css attribute, otherwise there was an error thrown. Maybe there should be some additional class for that instead which I do not know. Also, the two data-sets are not plotted in order (the second is plotted first) and are wrongly labeled in the legend, and appear horizontally connected to each other. The zoom function does not seem to work, etc, etc. I think this line graph thingy is possibly still work in progress and that might be the reason why it is not included in the docs yet. )**

, play around with it and see what it does. (I have not tested this and hope it works somehow.) If I understand correctly it should give you a zoomable line graph with data points `[0,0],[1,5],[3,8],[4,2],[5,6]` (x,y coordinate points) and the link below should reset the zoom **(edit: zooming does not work. maybe need to set some additional options for that)**

The whole thing seems to be based on this [Flot](https://github.com/flot/flot) JQuery chart library. So you might find some good further hints there or [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md), besides reading October's `{% app root %}/modules/system/assets/ui/js/chart.line.js` source code.

Comment: I tried using the chart-line API as shown in the commented documentation, It does not work. I tried couple other scenarios too, like keeping a list of data points , doesn't work that way too.

Comment: I have included an image and added some additional options (although the previous version did plot as well). It does plot something.
Have you seen my remark that you need to add a ```min-height``` to your ```div.control-chart```? But still, there is a lot here that does not seem to work yet. For example the described zooming function, or that consecutive datasets are just plotted after another horizontally, with the second appearing before the first. It seems this UI component is still work in progress which could be the reason that it is not documented yet.

Comment: Yes! the min-height was my issue. It displays the graph. The dataset only takes in coordinates. It doesn't accept other types of datapoints such as timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it